# Support server sent event with custom Java proxy servlet

Tags: servlets, proxy, reverse-proxy, server-sent-events, servlet-3.0

I have a custom implementation of reverse proxy server in Java Servlet. I want to support server sent events in my web application. To do that I need to modify my servlet code to support the SSE connection. I searched enough for examples of how to do that, but did not find anything. Can anyone provide me a direction about how to implement the SSE support in my Java Servlet?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify your servlet without posting code? It'll be hard

Comment: The servlet code is simple, it gets http request from client, add some custom headers & some logic and forwards the request to the backend servers. Once the backend server responds, sends it to the client. Its simple logic. What I don't understand is how to update this code to support live connection between client and server for server-sent-events.